# $NavigateTo doesn't do anything in created()

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

This is my code, I stored something in the localstorage and based on that I want to skip the first page. It succesfully get in the right case and but I don't go to the next page. I tested with 'EN', it even logs both logs, what is strange to me.

```
created() {
            console.log(this.$store.state.language);
            switch (this.$store.state.language) {
                case null:
                    console.log("Navigate to nowhere");
                    break;
                case "ZH":
                    console.log("Navigate to station zh");
                    this.$navigateTo(zhStationSelect);
                    break;
                case "EN":
                    console.log("Navigate to station eng");
                    this.$navigateTo(enStationSelect);
                    console.log("I can't be logged");
                    break;
            }
        },
```

Comment: It may be too early to run navigation code on created hook, as the previous navigation may be still in progress. If you just want to navigate to right page upon application launch, you may write the condition on the render function and return appropriate component.

Comment: @Manoj thanks for the new angle!